# Tiling squares with oblongs

Tags: co.combinatorics, tiling, packing-and-covering

An *oblong* is a rectangle whose width and length are consecutive integers: 1x2, 2x3, 3x4, etc. Does *N* exist such that it is possible to split the first *N* oblongs into 2 or more non-intersecting sets so that the oblongs in any of these sets tile a square?

Comment: It seems that searching the first 25 oblongs tiling squares with sidelength 60 and 40 may be promising.

Comment: Do you have any examples of oblongs tiling a square, Bernardo?

Comment: A converse problem of tiling oblongs with squares was posed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057290/oblongs-into-minimal-squares

Comment: Yes, @GerryMyerson: Tiles 2x3, 3x4, 4x5, 5x6, 6x7, 7x8, and 9x10 tile a square of side 16. I think they are pretty common.